# Can you read multiple variables on one line with Streamreader()?

Tags: c#, arrays, streamreader

I'm working in c# and wondering if it's possible to read back multiple variables and load into an array using `Streamreader.Readline()`?
Here's an example:

I have an array of different types being written using Streamwriter

```
foreach (Stuff stf in StuffArray)
{
    sw.WriteLine(" " + stf.car+ " " + stf.carOwned + " " + stf.carLocation);
}
sw.Close();
```

It writes out a text line that looks like:

> Magnum True Alabama

When I go to read it back the only option I have is to read the entire line with `Streamreader`.

I want to load it back like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < stfArray.Length; i++)
{
    stfArray[i] = new stfArray(Readline spot 1, Readline spot 2, Readline spot3)
}
```

So I can put the stuff back into the array or a new array in the exact same way it was when I extracted it.

Thanks!

Comment: I'ld suggest to use a different field separator. You could follow the CSV standard. Then you'ld have the [TextFieldParser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) class that can handle most "unfortunate" cases. Or language quicks. Anyway JSON should be the tool of choice for a text storage, IMO. Very simple to manage and Internet ready.

Answer (score 3):

Read the line, parse it (say with string.Split) and then take the tokens that you've parse and rehydrate your variables.

You probably want to use a more sophisticated format that word, space, etc. (think of cars whose model name contains a space, or places like New York). Pick a separator that will not occur in your strings.

Or better still, pick a well known serialization format like XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating string representation on your own, you are 100% sure about its format. Under any other occasion, you should consider something more robust, like serialization to XML and then writing it to a file.

In your situation I would recommend creating new collection of `Stuff` and add object, that lies in every line of your file, like:

```
List<Stuff> stuffItems = new List<Stuff>();
while(!streamReader.EndOfStream)
{
    string[] line = streamReader.ReadLine().Split(' ');
    stuffItems.Add(new Stuff(line[0], line[1], line[2]));
}
```

And now you can use this list however you want, for example overwrite old one calling `ToArray` method on list, etc.

But, again, I warn you about this approach: when you change your format, for example change delimiting character, you'd get exception :)